# Unexpected behaviour with assigning C++ references

Tags: c++, reference

Today i've see very strange thing while working with references.

Just one simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
  enum Type {
    FOO = 0,
    BAR = 1
  };
  virtual ~Base() {}
  virtual Type type() const = 0;
  int value_;
};

struct Foo : Base { 
    Foo() { value_ = 33; }
    virtual Type type() const { return FOO; }
};

struct Bar : Base { 
    Bar() { value_ = 44; }
    virtual Type type() const { return BAR; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    Base & b = foo;
    std::cout << b.type() << ", " << b.value_ << "\n";
    b = bar;
    std::cout << b.type() << ", " << b.value_ << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

What did you think output would be? I was really surprised when see it:

```
0, 33
0, 44
```

Tested on VS 2010, mingw 4.6, gcc 4.3. So, may be known secret of this magic?

[Ideone link example](http://ideone.com/ULGqjW)

Comment: What did *you* think output would be?

Comment: +correct, my english not so good as i want

Comment: I was not correcting your English. I was asking you why were you surprised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

References are like pointers in C++, with two important exceptions (aside from syntax):

- Their cannot be assigned to null
- They cannot be reassigned

So, when you call `b = bar`, you are not reassigning the reference; you are assigning the value of `bar` to the object referenced by `b`; in this case, you are assigning the value of `bar` to `foo`. So, in the second line, you will have a `Foo` object with a `value_` of `44`. Just what your output says.

Comment: Actually, the "like pointers" argument has a couple more pitfalls which can lead to more surprises if you think of it that way. A reference is not even an object, it is just an alias for a memory location and, while often implemented as a pointer, is not even guaranteed to take up space in memory. This is why, for example, you cannot create an array of references, and reference types do not have a valid sizeof. (sizeof a reference type returns the size of the type to which it is a reference).

Comment: @Agentlien Those are subtle details that don't apply much to this case, but you are absolutely right.

Comment: I realize that those are mostly subtleties, but when learning what a reference is, I don't think "alias of a memory address" is a more difficult concept than the usual "almost like a pointer, but not quite" explanation. And, once you finally do stumble upon the differences, that simplification can really mess with your intuition and understanding. It took me quite some time to realize what was up, the first time I tried to create a vector of references, given only a ridiculously obscure error message.

Comment: @Agentlien I agree again :) I think the main advantage of the pointer-like image is that it reinforces the idea that, in many cases where pointers can be used, references are a superior alternative.

Comment: I agree with that wholeheartedly. The juxtaposing of references and pointers is a clear advantage of that explanation. Although, it was that very idea of preferring references which led me to trying to create a vector of references. ;)

Comment: Also, it are another good reason for implementing private assigment operators and copy-constructors to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 3):

The `=` in `Base & b = foo;` and `b = bar;` are different operations.

`Base & b = foo;` assigns the reference to `foo`

`b = bar;` attempts a default member-wise assignment of `Base`. `b` still refers to `foo`. Its members have been re-assigned. It is still of type `Foo`.

Typical coding standards ([such as Google's](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Copy_Constructors)) often mandate that you should revoke the default copy constructor and assignment by making it private.